# Why do the WordWrap and AutoSize properties on a Text Box behave differently if the text boxes are added dynamically?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating some textboxes dynamically in a **custom control** (actually is just a panel with a binding source that adds other sub controls at runtime.

In some of those I am setting `WordWrap=True` because I am expecting large text. But the textbox has only  one line. Also I notice that I have to set the property `AutoSize` to False. When I add dynamically textboxes in a form everything is working fine (even without setting the AutoSize  and the WordWrap.

```
 Dim txt as new textbox
 txt.Multiline = True
 txt.AutoSize = False
 txt.Size = New Size(100, 50)
 txt.WordWrap = True
 txt.Location = New Point(10, 10)
 Me.Controls.Add(txt)   'Me is my custom Control
```

I checked the property `WordWrap` for the text box after I inserted them (with double click) and it is True.

Any ideas why I face this strange behaviour in my custom control?

Edit:
The problem is that I cannot make my text to wordwrap. So although I set MultiLine to true, AutoSize to false, WordWrap to True, the text is not changing lines. I don't want to add scrollbars.

Comment: Can you explain why you find this behavior 'strange'?

Comment: @Steve: I've edited the title to clarify.

Comment: Have you enabled Multiline property to true?

Comment: @Steve: Since It is behave differently when I add it to a custom control than how it behaves when I add them to a form I found it strange. Don't you? Maybe I had to rephrase my question to how to make the textbox to WordWrap.

Comment: @djadmin: As you can read in my code , yes I have already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I have to apologize.
The error was in my xml (I had MultiLine instead of Multiline), so my textbox was never Multiline.
Thanks  for your time, Sorry for spending it without meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the .Height of the TextBox when its .Text changes:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim txt As TextBox

    Sub maketb()
        txt = New TextBox
        txt.Multiline = True
        txt.Size = New Size(100, 50)
        txt.WordWrap = True
        txt.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    End Sub

    Sub SetHeight(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim target = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim fn = target.Font
        Dim gr = target.CreateGraphics()
        Dim lrMarginSize = target.Margin.Left + target.Margin.Right
        Dim tbMarginSize = target.Margin.Top + target.Margin.Bottom
        Dim h = gr.MeasureString(target.Text, fn, target.Width - lrMarginSize).Height + tbMarginSize
        target.Height = CInt(Math.Ceiling(h))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        maketb()
        AddHandler txt.TextChanged, AddressOf SetHeight
        txt.Text = "dfgd dfd gg hgljhhkjlh jhkkj hkjh hghjg hgjhgz hfjsdhfytu hgjahg ht gretyt jgagury agha gty ajhg ajgx"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to play with the height, because I add dynamically too many controls and I will complicate the sorting of the UI. Also I noticed that you add the textBox in a form. I don't face any problem with that. I Have a custom control (a panel that I feed with an xml (which has my controls definition)) and it creates the controls. Some of the controls are textboxes that I want to have them multiline, with no scrollbar and wordWrap. THat is the case that wordWrap doesn't work